# R Average if based on a condition (rank)

Tags: r, average

I have two dataframes, stocks' rank

```
 structure(list(Date = c("2010-01-31", "2010-02-28", "2010-03-31", 
    "2010-04-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-30"), Stock1 = c(1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 3L), Stock2 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L), Stock3 = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Stock4 = c(4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L), Stock5 = c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Stock6 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L), Stock7 = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Stock8 = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

and stocks' monthly return

```
structure(list(Date = c("2010-01-31", "2010-02-28", "2010-03-31", 
"2010-04-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-30"), Stock1 = c("10%", 
"2%", "3%", "4%", "6%", "3%"), Stock2 = c("-2%", "4%", "-30%", 
"-20%", "10%", "4%"), Stock3 = c("15%", "2%", "3%", "1%", "15%", 
"6%"), Stock4 = c("7%", "19%", "29%", "3%", "1%", "4%"), Stock5 = c("2%", 
"3%", "-2%", "4%", "-30%", "-20%"), Stock6 = c("19%", "29%", 
"15%", "2%", "3%", "1%"), Stock7 = c("1%", "2%", "2%", "4%", 
"1%", "5%"), Stock8 = c("20%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "0%", "60%"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want the average return based on the ranks of the stock and my final result would look like this

```
structure(list(Date = c("2010-01-31", "2010-02-28", "2010-03-31", 
"2010-04-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-30"), X1 = c("6%", "17%", 
"7%", "4%", "-9%", "6%"), X2 = c("9%", "2%", "29%", "5%", "6%", 
"-4%"), X3 = c("9%", "6%", "3%", "2%", "10%", "21%"), X4 = c("14%", 
"19%", "-8%", "4%", "6%", "4%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

please help! thanks!

Comment: Thanks for including the sample data and your desired output. Can you provide more info on what you have tried so far and what issue(s) you ran into?

Comment: the solutions i thought could work were terribly inefficient (even to a newbie like myself). For example, I thought of getting average of every rank by dividng every rank like -> stock_rank[stock_rank == 1]  but the problem is i have hundreds of ranks in the real file I need to work on. this is a simplified version

Comment: How the expected output has only 4 columns (`X1 : X4` )? Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: Hey @Ronak, just about to ask. My guess is because there are four ranks. Also, AlgoQuant, what scale do you need to do this on? E.g., 100 rows, 1,000, 10,000,000?

Comment: Character values for returns?

Comment: hey guys , Andrew is correct, it is because there are four ranks and i am trying to get the average value per rank.

Comment: the scale varies as im going to back test different time frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll call the "rank" object `idxs`, and the character "percentage" object `rets`. First convert those very unfortunate character values into numerics:

```
rets[,-1] <- as.numeric(t( apply(rets[-1], 1, sub, patt="%", repl="") ))
rets[,-1] <- rets[,-1]/100

> rets
        Date Stock1 Stock2 Stock3 Stock4 Stock5 Stock6 Stock7 Stock8
1 2010-01-31   0.10  -0.02   0.15   0.07   0.02   0.19   0.01    0.2
2 2010-02-28   0.02   0.04   0.02   0.19   0.03   0.29   0.02    0.1
3 2010-03-31   0.03  -0.30   0.03   0.29  -0.02   0.15   0.02    0.2
4 2010-04-30   0.04  -0.20   0.01   0.03   0.04   0.02   0.04    0.3
5 2010-05-31   0.06   0.10   0.15   0.01  -0.30   0.03   0.01    0.0
6 2010-06-30   0.03   0.04   0.06   0.04  -0.20   0.01   0.05    0.6
```

And now assign to each position in a 6 x 4 matrix the value of means of items chosen from rows of `rets` based on successive "rank" matrix values:

```
res <- matrix(NA, 6,4);  
for (rw in 1:nrow(rets) ){ 
            for( rk in 1:4){   # cyckle through possible "ranks"
               res[rw, rk]<- mean(unlist(rets[rw, which(idxs[rw,]==rk)]))
                         }}

> res
            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  0.05500000  0.08500000 0.0850000  0.13500000
[2,]  0.16500000  0.02333333 0.0600000  0.19000000
[3,]  0.07000000  0.29000000 0.0250000 -0.07500000
[4,]  0.04000000  0.05000000 0.0150000  0.03666667
[5,] -0.09333333  0.06000000 0.1000000  0.06000000
[6,]  0.06000000 -0.03666667 0.2133333  0.04000000
```